# How to find the number of subsets $A\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,10\}$ so that $A$ is related to $\{1,2,7\}$ or $A$ is related to $\emptyset$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}~$, and
$ARB$ if and only if $A$ union with $B$ has exactly 3 elements

a) Find the number of subsets $A \subseteq \{1,2,...,10\}~$ so that $A$ is related to $\{1,2,7\}$?

```
My solutions:
1) Choose 1 to be in the set, 1 way
2) Choose 2 to be in the set, 1 way
3) Choose 3 to be in the set, 1 way
4) Choose any number from S except 1,2,7 to be in the set, 2^7 ways
Ans: 2^7
```

b) Find the number of subsets $A \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,10\}~$ so that $A$ is related to $\emptyset$?

```
My solutions:
1) Choose any number from S, 10 ways
2) Choose any number from S except the previous, 9 ways
3) Choose any number from S except the 2 previous, 8 ways
Ans: 10 * 9 * 8
```

Comment: (a) If you choose $3$ to be in $A$, then $A \cup \{1,2,7\}$ contains at least $4$ elements; hence $A$ would not be related to $\{1,2,7\}$ in that case. (b) You're counting $\{1,2,3\}$ more than once (by choosing 1, 2, then 3; and also by choosing 1, 3, then 2.)

Comment: Does that mean there is only 1 subset, which is {1,2,7}?

Comment: For (a), that is correct.

Comment: Is there any way to get the number of subsets from a set, which are all unique plus they all must have 3 elements? Would it be 2^3?

Comment: $C(10,3)$ or $10C3$ or ${10\choose 3}$ ... it goes by various notations. And actually, my previous comment isn't true ... I thought that $A$ had to have 3 elements in that case as well. (See JMoravitz's answer below.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem states that the relation $\mathcal{R}$ is defined on $S=\{1,2,\dots,10\}$ as:

$$A\mathcal{R} B \Leftrightarrow |A\cup B|=3$$

We ask how many sets (and as a side question which are they) exist that are related to $\{1,2,7\}$.

Begin by noting that regardless of context, $|A\cup B|\geq |B|$, and in the case of finite sets $|A\cup B|>|B|$ in the case that $A\setminus B\neq \emptyset$.

For $A$ to be related to $\{1,2,7\}$ we would require $3=|\{1,2,7\}|\leq |A\cup \{1,2,7\}| = 3$, so the inequality in the middle must in fact be an equality and so $A\setminus B=\emptyset$.

We see then that for $A\mathcal{R}\{1,2,7\}$, this is true if and only if $A\subseteq \{1,2,7\}$

For example, $\{1,2\}\mathcal{R}\{1,2,7\}$ since $\{1,2\}\cup \{1,2,7\}=\{1,2,7\}$ is a set of size three.

The question becomes, how many subsets exist of $\{1,2,7\}$?  By earlier example, we know there are $2^3$ possible subsets of $\{1,2,7\}$, and the set of subsets of $\{1,2,7\}$ is denoted as $\mathcal{P}(\{1,2,7\})$.

For part (b), we ask, how many sets, $A$, (and which are they) such that $A\mathcal{R}\emptyset$

Since $A\cup \emptyset = A$ for all $A$, we see that this is true if and only if $|A|=3$, so $A$ is a subset of $S$ of size three.  By introductory counting techniques, we know that there will be $\frac{10!}{3!7!}=\binom{10}{3}$ sets of size three that are subsets of a ten element set.

*Note:* Order of elements in a set do not matter.  The set $\{1,2,3\}$ is the same thing as the set $\{3,1,2\}$.  When order matters, we call it an *ordered set*.